# AKS and Application Gateway network setup

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

Our AKS and Application Gateway are in different Vnets. From the AGIC documentation, the connection between AKS and Application Gateway is through a route table, as can be seen here [AGIC Github](https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/how-tos/networking.md).

However, we have a requirement that the route table should not exist between these two resources. AKS is using Kubenet and we cannot change it.

Is there another way to connect AKS and Application Gateway? Thanks.

Comment: https://azure.github.io/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/how-tos/networking/#with-kubenet

Answer (score 0):

***To connect AKS and Application Gateway, please try the below:***

You can enable AGIC on existing AKS cluster through Azure portal:

*Enable the **Application Gateway ingress** controller and add the created application gateway like below:*

[image]

If the above suggestion doesn't work in your scenario, then please **refer** the below links:

[Managing traffic to AKS through Azure Application Gateway using Application gateway Ingress Controller by SUDHAKARA RAO SAJJA](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/managing-traffic-aks-through-azure-application-gateway-sajja)

[Enable ingress controller add-on for existing AKS cluster with existing Azure application gateway | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-ingress-controller-add-on-existing)

Answer (score 0):

To connect AKS and Application Gateway, please try the below:

You can enable AGIC on existing AKS cluster through Azure portal:
[image]

Enable the Application Gateway ingress controller and add the created application gateway like below:

If the above suggestion doesn't work in your scenario, then please refer the below links:

Managing traffic to AKS through Azure Application Gateway using Application gateway Ingress Controller by SUDHAKARA RAO SAJJA

Enable ingress controller add-on for existing AKS cluster with existing Azure application gateway | Microsoft Docs